# GPA Calculator in C, doesn't work. probably type conversion error

Tags: c, type-conversion, pass-by-reference

The problem is I can't get the proper GPA. I am suspecting the divisions and type conversions. Below is the exact question I'm trying to do but I would like to learn what am I missing with my code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsqR1.jpg - They don't mention about credits so I simply ask it from the user in the program.

Edit: As seen from the question above, it should calculate the GPA but when I try with marks 50, 60, 70 respectively and 3 credits for each course, I get no sense outputs like 0.

(Original assignment wants 30 students and 5 courses but I defined them and changed them to 2 courses 1 student in order to test it in runtime.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_COURSES 2 // Homework asks for 5, change at the end
#define NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS 1 // Homework asks for 30, change at the end

void calculateCourse(int *letterGradePoints, int *credit); // Func. prototype
float calculateStudentGpa(); // Func. prototype

int main()
{
    // Store gpa s of students in an array
    float studentGpas[NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS; ++i)
    {
        /*DEBUG*/printf("----\nPROGRAM IS IN MAIN FOR LOOP\n----\n");
        studentGpas[i] = calculateStudentGpa();
    }

    // Print all gpas
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS; ++i)
    {
        printf("\nGPA of student %d is : %d        ", i + 1, studentGpas[i]);
    }
    // Find min gpa
    int min = studentGpas[0];
    for(i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS; ++i)
        if(min > studentGpas[i])
            min = studentGpas[i];
    // Find max gpa
    int max = studentGpas[0];
    for(i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS; ++i)
        if(max < studentGpas[i])
            max = studentGpas[i];

    // Print min and max
    printf("Min gpa is : %d        Max gpa is : %d", min, max);

    return 0;
}

float calculateStudentGpa()
{
    /*DEBUG*/printf("\nPROGRAM IS IN calculateStudentGpa FUNCTION");
    /* Dealing with a single students gpa */

    int credit[NUMBER_OF_COURSES];
    int letterGradePoints[NUMBER_OF_COURSES];

    int i; int debug = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COURSES; ++i)
    {
        /*DEBUG*/ if(debug == 0) { /*DEBUG*/printf("\nPROGRAM IS IN calculateStudentGpa FUNCTION for LOOP\n"); debug++; } // Print this one once

        calculateCourse(&letterGradePoints[i], &credit[i]);

        /*DEBUG*/printf("\nPROGRAM IS IN calculateStudentGpa FUNCTION for LOOP\n");
        /*DEBUG*/printf("\n[DEBUG] i in calculateStudentGpa : %d", i);
        /*DEBUG*/printf("\n[DEBUG] letterGradePoints[i] in calculateStudentGpa : %d", letterGradePoints[i]);
        /*DEBUG*/printf("\n[DEBUG] credit[i] in calculateStudentGpa : %d\n", credit[i]);
    }
    /*DEBUG*/printf("\nPROGRAM HAS ..PASSED.. calculateStudentGpa FOR LOOP");

    float gpa; float up = 0; float down = 0;

    /* Either we need to have
     * (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COURSES; ++i) AND indexes of arrays as i
     * or
     * (i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_COURSES; ++i) AND indexes of arrays as i - 1
     * below in 2 for loops!!!!
     */
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COURSES; ++i)
    {
        up += (letterGradePoints[i] * credit[i]); // Might need (float)
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_COURSES; ++i)
    {
        down += credit[i - 1];
    }

    gpa = up / down;

    /* We are done with a single student, we need all 30 students */

    return gpa;
}

void calculateCourse(int *letterGradePoints, int *credit)
{
    /*DEBUG*/printf("\n--------------------------------------");
    /*DEBUG*/printf("\nVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV");
    /*DEBUG*/printf("\nPROGRAM IS IN calculateCourse FUNCTION\n");

    /* Dealing with a single course */

    int labMark, midtermMark, finalMark;

    printf("\nEnter lab mark : ");
    scanf("%d", &labMark);
    printf("Enter midterm mark : ");
    scanf("%d", &midtermMark);
    printf("Enter final mark : ");
    scanf("%d", &finalMark);

    float average =
    (
        (float) (0.5 * finalMark)
        +
        (float) (0.4 * midtermMark)
        +
        (float) (0.1 * labMark)
    ); // Might need (float)

    /*DEBUG*/printf("\n[DEBUG] average : %f", average);

    // int letterGradePoints; // I decided to use pass by reference in order to return 2 values

    if(average >=  0) *letterGradePoints = 0;
    if(average >= 50) *letterGradePoints = 1;
    if(average >= 60) *letterGradePoints = 2;
    if(average >= 70) *letterGradePoints = 3;
    if(average >= 80) *letterGradePoints = 4;
    /*DEBUG*/printf("\n[DEBUG] letterGradePoints in calculateCourse : %d\n", *letterGradePoints);

    // int credit; // I decided to use pass by reference in order to return 2 values

    printf("Enter the credit for the course : ");
    scanf("%d", credit);
    /*DEBUG*/printf("\n[DEBUG] *credit in calculateCourse : %d\n", *credit);
    /*DEBUG*/printf("/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\\n");
    /*DEBUG*/printf("--------------------------------------\n");

    /* We are done with a single course, we need all 5 courses for the gpa */
}
```

Comment: 'for(i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_COURSES; ++i)' leads to out-of-bounds access: 'down += credit[i];' which is a bit strange, 'cos you correctly index the array in the previous loop:(

Comment: Also, you need to explain what you probem is.  What inputs you used, what outputs you get.  What happened that should not happen.  What did not happen that should have happened.

Comment: Oh, you're right. In the calculateStudentGpa() function I am going out of bounds in the 3rd for loop, fixing that!

edit: i fixed it by keeping the for loop same but accessing to credit[i - 1] if im not wrong, this should do the trick there.

Comment: You're printing the gpa as an integer with `%d`. Use `%f` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the GPA as an integer instead of as a floating point number. Change

```
printf("\nGPA of student %d is : %d", i + 1, studentGpas[i]);
```

to

```
printf("\nGPA of student %d is : %f", i + 1, studentGpas[i]);
```

Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for a list of format specifiers used by `printf`.

Comment: Yeah that was another mistake, it seems like it's fixed now, thank you. I couldn't get my local copies to work so I copy pasted this code from my post here. I should quit programming already :(

Comment: @pysn If I had to quit programming for a typo like this I would have quitted about 10 years ago :-) Don't give up!

Comment: I mean I spent 6 hours+ for this and couldn't realize it.